# Possible to get the size_in_bytes for records matching a specific query?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [documentation on the stats api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) indicates that we can do the following:

```
http://es.cluster.ip.addr:9200/indexname/_stats
```

Which resuls in an output like:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": {
    "primaries": {
      "docs": {
        "count": 32930,
        "deleted": 0
      },
      "store": {
        "size_in_bytes": 3197332,
        "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
      },
      // ... etc
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, is there a way to obtain the file size for a specific set of records, specific such as when we run a search query:

```
http://es.cluster.ip.addr:9200/indexname/type/_search?q=identifier:123
```

So essentially, the size_in_bytes for all records matching the identifier 123?

Comment: I don't think so. You want to see how much disk space some documents take?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yeah and besides seperating them into an index per identifier i'm not quite sure how to go about that.

Comment: The disk space used cannot be easily split into documents because there is no single storage space for one document. There are data structures that are "shared" between documents, the best example being the inverted index which holds terms gathered from all documents. Why do you need to know the size on disk for a single document? That's an unusual request

Comment: @AndreiStefan It's a good point that you have got there and not one that I had considered. Essentially, am building a data warehouse of sorts, I want to be able to know how much storage space each user is making use of through the various channels, so file storage x gb, database storage x gb, backup storage x gb, etc. Comparing this against other users i'd be able to work out a very rough average for % of systems utilization.

Comment: Right, interesting. How do you define the boundaries between users? In the ES world, if practical (not that many users), the data could be hold on separate indices, or separate shards of the same index (but in this case you could place documents from multiple users on the same shard). Maybe, also, track the documents sizes at indexing time with your own tracking method (size of the JSON itself, for example). There is one other aspect: are your users allowed to update/delete documents?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Basically, it's a log of hardware telemetry data. Each log entry is assigned to an entity. The data that is collected comes in various formats and is also backed up. What I am essentially trying to do is say for each entity, how much storage is used for x, y, z and compared to other entities what is the % of total systems utilization. I could have one index per entity, say `log_entityid` then I could use stat to check the size of the data for each but to my basic understanding it would be better in terms of performance to keep the data in one index when scaling?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Interesting thought on tracking the size on creation however, ES might hold this record in multiple nodes so if I were to try to limit this to storing data in one shard on one node then if the node fails the data is gone? Also, the data is created or removed but never updated.

Comment: I don't think there is any easy option. ES knows about shard size, index size and number of documents. You'd have to get creative on how to approximate or evaluate the size of each document. You could take the size on disk of an index and the number of document in it and calculate an average on disk size for a single document. Then extrapolate this and calculate the size on disk an user is using by multiplying [average_size_of_one_document] with how many documents an user has.

Comment: @AndreiStefan You're absolutely right, given that this index contains data of only one type, it would be pretty accurate to just average the total documents in order to work work out the size per document. Thanks so much!